# Не создается связь многие ко многим Asp.Net Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Создал модель для связи многие ко многим , и в методе где создаю книгу ещё делаю добавление связи книги с издательствами

Вот код сервиса

```
public void Post(PostBookView book)
    {
        var bookModel = Mapper.Map<PostBookView, Book>(book);
        var bookPublicationHousesModel = new BookPublicationHouse();

        var bookId = bookModel.BookId;

        foreach (var publicationHouse in book.PublicationHouses)
        {
            bookPublicationHousesModel.BookPublicationHouseId = publicationHouse.PublicationHouseId;
            bookPublicationHousesModel.BookId = bookId;
        }
        _bookRepository.Create(bookModel);
        _bookPublicationHouseRepository.Create(bookPublicationHousesModel);//на этом месте все ломается 
    }
```

Исключение выдает здесь

```
public void Create(T entity)
    {
        Entities.Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();//SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'BookPublicationHouses' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

    }
```

То есть книга создается и выводится в таблице, а связь - нет

Искал решение этой ошибки ,но ничего по делу не нашел

Если нужно больше информации - пишите

Вот модель для связи

```
public class BookPublicationHouse
{
    [Key]
    public int BookPublicationHouseId { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    [Write(false)]
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    public int PublicationHouseId { get; set; }
    [Write(false)]
    public virtual PublicationHouse PublicationHouse { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Каким образом вы создаете базу данных?

Comment: EF Core или "классический" вариант? Какая версия? Не пробовали Fluent API использовать?

Comment: @VadimBondaruk через миграции

Comment: @XelaNimed EF Core ,нет не пробовал

Comment: Я использовал Fluent API для создания связей между таблицами. Подробно здесь: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.6.php

Comment: @XelaNimed хорошо,попробую так , а на вид метод создания связи выглядит рабочим ?

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но мне кажется что нет. У Вас определен один ключ, а для промежуточной таблицы их необходимо два. Посмотрите в примере по ссылке выше: `.HasKey(t => new { t.StudentId, t.CourseId });`, так называемый составной ключ.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых я пытался ещё не существующую книгу связать с издательствами ,поэтому для начала нужно было создать книгу (я это делал в конце метода)

зачем нужно было достать эту книгу по Id `var bookViewModel =
                Mapper.Map<Book, PostBookView>(_bookRepository.GetById(bookModel.Id));`

а затем уже делать связь.

Вот весь метод

```
public void Post(PostBookView postBookView)
    {
        var bookModel = Mapper.Map<PostBookView, Book>(postBookView);
        _bookRepository.Create(bookModel);
        var bookViewModel =
            Mapper.Map<Book, PostBookView>(_bookRepository.GetById(bookModel.Id));
        var bookPublicationHousesModel = new BookPublicationHouse();

        var bookId = bookViewModel.Id;

        foreach (var publicationHouse in postBookView.PublicationHouses)
        {
            bookPublicationHousesModel = new BookPublicationHouse { BookId = bookId, PublicationHouseId = publicationHouse.Id };
            _bookPublicationHouseRepository.Create(bookPublicationHousesModel);
        }
    }
```

P.S. Связь таблиц, как это сделал я, работает

Comment: В промежуточной таблице `BookPublicationHouse` сколько у Вас внешних ключей? Я имею ввиду `BookId` у Вас ссылается на таблицу с книгами или просто содержит ключ книги без связи?